# Assigning a comment without committing in Git

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to assign comments to individual files for commit without doing it on each commit?

For example I have 5 files:

```
secret1.txt
secret2.txt
secret3.txt
secret4.txt
secret5.txt
```

Currently if I want to commit each one of these files with a different comment I am doing:

```
git add secret1.txt
git commit -m 'first secret'

git add secret2.txt
git commit -m 'second secret'

git add secret3.txt
git commit -m 'third secret'

...

git push origin master
```

That's 5 different commits for 5 files before the push. Is there a way to assign 5 individual comments and only commit once?

Answer (score 1):

No, these strings aren't "comments", they're **commit messages**, and they're intrinsically part of a commit, not a specific file.

You can add all five files in a single commit, and use a multi-line commit message to add details about the specific files, or you can add each file as a single commit with a specific commit message.

Answer (score -1):

Comments are ***linked*** with the commits in git. So, if you want to add different comments to different files then it has to be done in separate commits.
Other option is, you can add the comments (multi-line) to single commit and those comments will be displayed with all the files.

**After command** `git commit`
[image]

Comment: I see. I know about ```git add *``` and was trying to not assign a consolidated comment to each file being committed.

Comment: Yes, no matter how many files you commit. The comments are specific to the commit and are not linked to files in a commit.